# How to alter text order of words in psql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table, with id and name fields.
The name field has content in the form of: Clyde, Shire of
How do I UPDATE the name field so that it reads: Shire of Clyde

Comment: Look at *Examples* section here [UPDATE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html).

Comment: Maybe the `split_part` function helps.

Comment: @Ahmed - thanks for that. I had answered using a regex <gulp...> when `SPLIT_PART()` is **so** much simpler in this case - see below. You've saved me from **complete** embarassment! :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can do stuff like this easily enough using regular expressions (regexes). [Regular-Expressions.info](https://www.regular-expressions.info/) is an excellent starting place for all things regex - their quick start guide is [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html).

[EDIT]

There is a far simpler way of doing this, and probably much more efficiently, by using the [`SPLIT_PART()`](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-string-functions/postgresql-split_part/) function ([manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-string.html)). Regular expressions are very powerful, but they are also expensive and it is good practice to avoid them **when and if** possible. I've left the regex stuff in, but this query will do what you want (fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=b2f1d6f8aaeec1c8e7341ce061c5bc4b)):

```
SELECT
  SPLIT_PART(x, ', ', 2) || ' ' || SPLIT_PART(x, ', ', 1)  -- Optionally, use the TRIM() function around this whole line
FROM
  test;
```

Result:

```
result
Shire of Clyde
Mull of Kintyre
Lough Ness
Firth of Forth
```

Regex solution - not appropriate in this case, but may be helpful?

To solve your problem, I did the following (all of the code below is available on the fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=f5325bef5660e4709b468c7c5308804a)):

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
  x TEXT NOT NULL
);
```

And populate with some sample data:

```
INSERT INTO test VALUES
('Clyde, Shire of'),
('Kintyre, Mull of'),
('Ness, Lough'),
('Forth, Firth of');
```

Then, run the following query:

```
SELECT
  REGEXP_REPLACE(x, '(.+), (.*)', '\2 \1')
FROM test;
```

Result:

```
result
Shire of Clyde
Mull of Kintyre
Lough Ness
Firth of Forth
```

Explanation of the query (incl. regex):

The query uses PostgreSQL's [`REGEXP_REPLACE()`](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-string-functions/regexp_replace/) function ([manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html)) - its syntax is:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(source, pattern, replacement_string,[, flags])
```

The `source` is the field you want to modify, the `pattern` is a regex that you want to match and the `replacement_string` is what you want in the regex's place - confusingly (it should really be called `replacement_pattern`), it can (and normally is) also a regex (although, strictly speaking, even a "normal" string is also a regex).

You can check out the [flags](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#POSIX-EMBEDDED-OPTIONS-TABLE) in the documentation - the important ones are `g` (**not** in the linked table - why, I don't know) and `i` meaning `case-insensitive`.

`pattern` regex: `'(.+), (.*)'`

- `(` - start a "capturing group" - see quick start above and references therein.
- `.+` `.` is a "meta-character", i.e. it has a special meaning in regexes - it means any character. `+` is also a meta-character meaning 0 or more repeats of any character - implicit assumption on my part - that your string is in the form you have indicated in the question.
- `,`  - comma followed by space. These are string literals (neither character has any special meaning in regexes. Your question says that you have a string, followed by a comma, followed by a space, followed by another string.
- `.*` `*` is another meta-character - meaning 1 or more of any character.

`replacement_string` regex: `'\2 \1'`

- the capturing groups number 1 and number 2 are referred to as `\1` and `\2`, so I just swap them round, as you want. Now, the first string is at the end and the second one is at the beginning. The comma has been removed but they are still separated by the space.

Finally, to change your base table, do this:

```
UPDATE test
SET x = REGEXP_REPLACE(x, '(.+), (.*)', '\2 \1');
```

Then,

```
SELECT * FROM test;
```

Result:

```
x
Shire of Clyde
Mull of Kintyre
Lough Ness
Firth of Forth
```